# How to delete a ViewModel and Model in a collection of it's parent's ViewModel and Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to figure out the best way to delete a model (and hence it's VM) and despite searching around quite a bit I haven't found a satisfactory answer for my situation.

The simplified version is, given a model that contains a list of itself, and it's subsequent viewmodel that contains a collection of itself, in what order should things be notified and deleted?

My working assumption is that the flow goes something like

1. User clicks delete on a child view
2. The view calls the DeleteChild command from the parent view's datacontext, passing it's own datacontext as a parameter
3. The parent VM notifies it's Model (the parent model) that it's deleting one of it's children's VMs
4. The parent VM removes the child VM from it's collection
5. The parent model removes the child model

It seems almost overly complex, and this method would require separate logic to delete the root item however having the view call it's own deleteself command would mean null items in the list and collection necessitating communication with the parent VM and model. Is there a 'typical' way to delete models?

If I had to write something right now it would look as follows

*Model*

```
public class NestingBoxModel
{
    public NestingBoxModel()
    {
        NestingBoxModels = new List<NestingBoxModel>();
    }

    public List<NestingBoxModel> NestingBoxModels { get; }

    public Boolean ShouldBeRemoved { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notfies child to prepare for removal
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="child">Child to be notified</param>
    public void DeleteChild(NestingBoxModel child)
    {
       NestingBoxModels.Find(c => c == child)?.PrepareForRemoval();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notifes all children to prepare for removal
    /// Marked as ready for removal
    /// </summary>
    public void PrepareForRemoval()
    {
        NestingBoxModels.ForEach(nb => nb.PrepareForRemoval());

        ShouldBeRemoved = true;
    }

    // Other stuff for saving and eventually removing the model
}
```

*ViewModel*

```
public class NestingBoxViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public NestingBoxViewModel()
    {
        Model = new NestingBoxModel();
        ViewModels = new ObservableCollection<NestingBoxViewModel>();
        DeleteChildCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(DeleteChild);
        DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(PrepareForRemoval);
    }

    public NestingBoxModel Model { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<NestingBoxViewModel> ViewModels { get; private set; }

    public ICommand DeleteChildCommand { get; }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds, notifies, and removes child viewmodel
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="child">Child viewmodel to be removed</param>
    private void DeleteChild(object child)
    {
        var matchingchild = ViewModels.First<NestingBoxViewModel>(vm => vm.Equals(child));
        if (matchingchild != null)
        {
            Model.DeleteChild(matchingchild.Model);
            ViewModels.Remove(matchingchild);
            matchingchild.PrepareForRemoval();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prepares for garbage collection
    /// </summary>
    public void PrepareForRemoval()
    {
        ViewModels.ToList<NestingBoxViewModel>().ForEach(vm => vm.PrepareForRemoval());

        Model = null;
        ViewModels = null;
    }
}
```

*View*

```
<Border Width="5">
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <Button Content="New NestingBox" Command="{Binding DeleteChildCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:NestingBoxView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

If it isn't messy it's sure confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. User clicks delete on a child view
> 2. The view calls the DeleteChild command from the parent view's datacontext, passing it's own datacontext as a parameter
> 3. The parent VM notifies it's Model (the parent model) that it's deleting one of it's children's VMs
> 4. The parent VM removes the child VM from it's collection
> 5. The parent model removes the child model

That's pretty much it. I'd add

> 3a. the Model broadcasts a notification about one of its children being removed

because the view model should not change a view model collection that mirrors a model collection on its own. Reasoning: the model collection may well change without the view model doing anything, so it has to react to changes anyway and you get reactions to changes originating from the view model for free.

Comment: Excellent. So the notification broadcast would essentially just be an event that every parent subscribes to? In my particular application most parents will have single-digit number of children so I was also considering handing down a callback function, and having the child control respond to the UI directly and then notify it's parent rather than the view binding to it's parent's function. For multiple reasons the model does use events, as you suggested.

Comment: Events are one option, but it really can be anything like event aggregator or some message bus. There's a lot to say about CQRS...